# Validar una variable con un campo de mi bd

Tags: php, variables, validación

Estoy desarrollando una página Web, que tiene usuarios correspondietes a ciudades, para ser más precisa esta construida de la siguiente forma (Y esta hecha en Postgres)

USER

```
┌────────────┬───────────┐
│ cv_usuario │ Password  │
├────────────┼───────────┤
│        011 │ Ciudad1   │
│        022 │ Ciudad2   │
└────────────┴───────────┘
```

Y por otra parte tengo la tabla CIUDADES

```
┌────────────┬───────────┬─────────────┐
│ cv_ciudad  │  nombre   │  Habitantes │
├────────────┼───────────┼─────────────┤
│ 011        │ Del Valle │      123823 │
│ 022        │ Madero    │      998337 │
└────────────┴───────────┴─────────────┘
```

Básicamente mi sitio web necesita hacer lo siguiente:

- Login (que ingresa con el nombre de usuario correspondiente a su clave de ciudad)
- Cuando acceda abre un mapa que tengo montado con una api de google, el cual que tiene las capas de las ciudades
- Cuando le das en el botón VER FICHA te debe cargar todos los datos correspondientes a esa ciudad (lanza una consulta con los datos correspondiente), PERO, si le das clic en una ciudad diferente, debe mostrar un mensaje: `¡No tiene permiso para acceder a los datos de esta ciudad!`

Hasta ahorita he logrado acceder al dar clic a la ciudad con la que acceso pero no he podido lograr validar con una ciudad diferente. 
Estoy trabajando con php

Mi codigo php del Login donde construyo mi valiable de inicio de sesion

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['varname'] = $userName;
echo "Welcome " . $userName;
header("Location: ../index.php"); //Me dirijo a index de mi página que contiene el mapa
```

En mi mapa muestro una ficha pequeña con un enlace, el cual contiene un xml donde manejo un predato para dirigir a la ficha de información con su correspondiente clave

```
<campo predato="CIUDAD|http://127.0.0.1/CIUDADES/verficha.php?varname=">
  <nombre>clavegeo</nombre>
  <alias>Ficha</alias>
</campo>
```

y en mi ficha de información tengo lo siguiente:
Reasigno lo almacenado en el inicio de sesion en otra variable

```
$ciudad = $_SESSION['varname'];
```

y alli viene mi duda como valido para que solo muestre lo que corresponde a esa ciudad. al momento tengo algo asi

```
if ($ciudad) {
    $query="Select *
            from ciudad
            where cv_ciudad
                in ($ciudad) )
                ;";

    $result = pg_query($query) or die('Query failed: ' . 
              pg_last_error());
    $rows = pg_num_rows ($result);
    $i = pg_num_fields($result);
}
else {
    echo "<br><center>¡No tiene permiso para acceder a los datos de esta ciudad!";
    echo $ciudad;
}
```

Sin embargo si doy clic a otra ciudad y le doy en -mostrar ficha- me manda perfectamente la consulta de esa ciudad aun que no corresponda con la clave con la que acceso en el login :(

Espero puedan ayudarme amigos, de antemano gracias

Comment: Bienvenida a Stackoverflow. No entendí tu planteamiento. En muchos casos uno se bloquea porque ni siquiera tiene **un planteamiento claro de lo que quiere hacer** y eso debido a una excesiva preocupación sobre el cómo hacerlo. Recomendaría que te despegues 5 minutos del PC, que te tomes un café o agua o lo que tomes. Y que luego describas en tu mente (o en papel)  lo que quieres hacer. Luego te preguntas por cómo hacerlo. A veces la solución del problema la encuentras cuando lo planteas bien (me ha pasado muchas veces). Quiero decir que  se necesita más claridad en tu pregunta. Saludos.

Comment: Gracias por el consejo, si se que es lo que tengo que hacer, pero no sé como hacerlo, tal vez no me supe explicar, en resumen es: mostrar la ciudad correspondiente a la clave que ingreso el usuario, por ejemplo el usuario 015 (nombre de usuario) corresponde a la ciudad de "Kansas" y esa es la ciudad que le permitirá consultar, cuando de clic a otra ciudad que no corresponda a su nombre de usuario mostrar el mensaje de error

Comment: Puedes [editar la pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/142623/edit)  explicando con mayor claridad lo que quieres lograr, lo que estás haciendo y en dónde encuentras la dificultad. Sin duda alguien con mayor experiencia aquí podrá ayudarte, pero se requiere entender lo mejor posible el problema y el contexto en que se desarrolla la aplicación.

Comment: Si es muy fácil plantear una pregunta. No sueltes el problema de entrada. Empieza diciendo lo que tienes: *tengo un formulario donde hay una lista de ciudades, en esa lista el usuario selecciona una y luego quiero consultar los elementos X en la base de datos tomando como criterio esa ciudad seleccionada, bla, bla, bla*... Luego nos dices el problema: *el problema es que cuando Fulano selecciona una ciudad luego aparecen los datos de todas las ciudades menos de esa que seleccionó* y luego nos muestras el código: *este es el código donde hago la consulta una vez seleccionada la ciudad*...

Answer (score 0):

hasta donde entendí , el usuario que inicia sesión tiene pre asignada una ciudad. el cual solo debe de ver esta.

si ese es el caso deberías tener

1. la id_ciudad asignada al Usuario
2. capturar el id_ciudad_seleccionada.
3. hacer un simple if

.

```
if(id_ciudad.equals(id_ciudad_seleccionada))
{
      //realizar llamada 
}
else
{
     //mandar mensaje.
}
```

o bueno si lo quieres hacer desde la query ..

solo tendrías que cambiar tu query

```
   Select * from CIUDADES 
    where cv_ciudad = (select cv_ciudad  from USER WHERE cv_usuario = '011 ' and password = 'Ciudad1' and  cv_usuario  = $ciudad)
```

La magia esta en

```
select cv_ciudad  from USER WHERE cv_usuario = '011 ' and password = 'Ciudad1' and  cv_usuario  = $ciudad
```

buscas el usuario  011 con password Ciudad1 y ademas tiene que cumplir que la ciudad sea igual al que previamente as seleccionado.. si existe te devuelve la ciudad caso contrario no hará nada.

espero sea de tu ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que tienes un pequeño detalle en tu logica, porque para hacer lo que pides primero tendrías que haber "amarrado" a los usuarios con las ciudades, lo puedes hacer de manera manual en tu BD, o haz un `form` donde puedas registras a los `usuarios` con su ciudad respectiva y al final para consultarlo pues lo puedes hacer con un `query` amarrando los dos que creo que es lo más fácil.

```
 $query= "SELECT c.cv_ciudad, c.nombres, c.habitantes, u.cv_usuario FROM  cv_ciudad c, cv_usuario u WHERE c.cv_ciudad=u.cv_ciudad";
```

Answer (score -1):

if($_GET['varname'] == $_SESSION['varname']){
procesa
}else{
no procesa
}
aunque no entendi mucho que datos guardas en la session :)

Comment: Gracias por tu contribución, te sugiero realizar el [tour] del sitio para que conozcas su funcionamiento. En cuanto a la realización de respuestas, que estas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad te sugiero revisar [answer].